# Difference between OrdinalEncoder and LabelEncoder

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, preprocessing, encoding

I was going through the official documentation of scikit-learn learn after going through a book on ML and came across the following thing:

In the Documentation it is given about `sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()` whereas in the book it was given about `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()`, when I checked their functionality it looked same to me. Can Someone please tell me the difference between the two please?

Answer (score 49):

Afaik, both have the same functionality. A bit difference is the idea behind. `OrdinalEncoder` is for converting features, while `LabelEncoder` is for converting target variable.

That's why `OrdinalEncoder` can fit data that has the shape of `(n_samples, n_features)` while `LabelEncoder` can only fit data that has the shape of `(n_samples,)` (though in the past one used `LabelEncoder` within the loop to handle what has been becoming the job of `OrdinalEncoder` now)

Comment: When to use `OrdinalEncoder`?

Comment: See also https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12720

Comment: As per the documentation cited at that link, "[`LabelEncoder` is] not intended to be used on features, only on supervised learning targets."

Answer (score 27):

As for differences in `OrdinalEncoder` and `LabelEncoder` *implementation*, the accepted answer mentions the **shape** of the data:

- `OrdinalEncoder` is for 2D data with the shape `(n_samples, n_features)`
- `LabelEncoder` is for 1D data with the shape `(n_samples,)`

Maybe that's why the [top-voted answer suggests](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/39319/77875) `OrdinalEncoder` is for the **"features"** (often a 2D array), whereas `LabelEncoder` is for the **"target variable"** (often a 1D array).

That's also why a `OrdinalEncoder` would get an error if trying to fit on 1D data: `OrdinalEncoder().fit(['a','b'])`

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

Another difference between the encoders is the **name of their learned parameter**;

- `LabelEncoder` learns `classes_`
- `OrdinalEncoder` learns `categories_`

Notice the differences when **fitting** `LabelEncoder` vs `OrdinalEncoder`, and the differences in the values of the **learned parameters**.

- `LabelEncoder.fit(...)` accepts a 1D array; `LabelEncoder.classes_` is 1D
- `OrdinalEncoder.fit(...)` accepts a 2D array; `OrdinalEncoder.categories_` is 2D.

```
    LabelEncoder().fit(['a','b']).classes_
    # >>> array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
    
    OrdinalEncoder().fit([['a'], ['b']]).categories_
    # >>> [array(['a', 'b'], dtype=object)]
```

This is consistent with the idea that

- `OrdinalEncoder` is for your `X` aka your input features (2D)
- [`LabelEncoder` is for your `y` aka your target variables (1D)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) ([also mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930953/1175496)):

> `LabelEncoder` should be used to encode target values, i.e. y, and not the input X.

Other encoders that work in 2D, including `OneHotEncoder`, also use the property `categories_`

[More info here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) about the dtype `<U1` (little-endian , Unicode, 1 byte; i.e. a string with length 1)

**EDIT**

In the [comments to my answer, Piotr disagrees with my answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/difference-between-ordinalencoder-and-labelencoder/64177#comment69359_64177); but Piotr points out the difference between ordinal **encoding** and label **encoding** more generally (vs differences in their implementation). Piotr's right about the general definitions/usages:

- **Ordinal encoding** should be used for *ordinal variables* (where order matters, like `cold`, `warm`, `hot`);
- vs **Label encoding** should be used for *non-ordinal* (aka *nominal*) variables (where order doesn't matter, like `blonde`, `brunette`)

This is a good point, but this question asks about the `sklearn` classes/*implementation*. *If you want **ordinal  encoding** like Piotr describes (i.e. where order is preserved); **you must do the ordinal encoding yourself*** (*neither `OrdinalEncoder` nor `LabelEncoder` can infer the order!* See the `OrdinalEncoder` constructor parameter called `categories`).

As for implementation it seems like `LabelEncoder` and `OrdinalEncoder` have **consistent behavior** as far as the **chosen integers**. They *both* assign integers based on *alphabetical order*. For example:

```
OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform([['cold'],['warm'],['hot']]).reshape((1,3))
# >>> array([[0., 2., 1.]])

LabelEncoder().fit_transform(['cold','warm','hot'])
# >>> array([0, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Notice how **both** encoders assigned integers in **alphabetical order** 'c'<'h'<'w'.

**But this part is important:** Notice how **neither** encoder got the **"real" order** correct (i.e. the real order should reflect the temperature, where order is 'cold'<'warm'<'hot'; 0<1<2). If the encoders used the "real" order, the value `'warm'` would have been assigned the integer 1 (instead of the integer 2)

*[In the blog post referenced by Piotr](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-categorical-variable-encoding-305f3361fd02), the author **does not even use `OrdinalEncoder()`***. To achieve **ordinal encoding** the author **does it manually**: maps each temperature to a "real" order integer, using a dictionary like `{'cold':0, 'warm':1, 'hot':2}`:

> Refer to this code using Pandas, where first we need to **assign the real order of the variable through a dictionary**... Though its very straight forward but it requires coding to tell ordinal values and what is the actual mapping from text to integer as per the order.

In other words, if you're wondering whether to use `OrdinalEncoder`, please note `OrdinalEncoder` **may not actually provide "ordinal encoding" the way you expect**!

**EDIT**
@Magnus Persson pointed out that the `OrdinalEncoder` class accepts an argument called `categories`, which you can use to
**determine/assign the resulting order**.

```
OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['cold','warm','hot']])
    .fit_transform([['hot'],['warm'],['warm'],['cold']])
    .reshape((1,-1))[0]

# Output is:
# >>> array([[2., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

**EDIT**
@lbcommer pointed out that there is a Python library [`category_encoders`, which has an `OrdinalEncoder` class](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/ordinal.html#ordinal). Note how even that class constructor has a `mapping` argument so you can choose the resulting order:

> the value of ‘mapping’ should be a dictionary of ‘original_label’ to ‘encoded_label’....
> example mapping:  `{‘col’: ‘col1’, ‘mapping’: {None: 0, ‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2}}, {‘col’: ‘col2’, ‘mapping’: {None: 0, ‘x’: 1, ‘y’: 2}}`

Comment: I strongly disagree. Concepts behind these encoding techniques fundamentally differ. It's not only about implementation in a library.

Comment: worth mentioning that np.NaN is encoded by LabelEncoder, but triggers an error with OrdinalEncoder.

OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform([['cold'],['warm'],['hot'],[np.NAN]]).reshape((1,4))
LabelEncoder().fit_transform(['cold','warm','hot',np.NAN])

Comment: The python library category_encoders includes an implementation for ordinal encoding where it is possible to pass a mapping dictionary as argument so, using that library, it wouldn't be necessary to map manually.

Comment: Thanks @lbcommer , I will mention this library, but it's funny to me; isn't it inevitable that we humans must still provide "the mapping dictionary", as you say...

Comment: When `OrdinalEncoder` is initiated it takes a parameter `categories` which according to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html if given should be an ordered list, thus doing `OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['cold','warm','hot']]).fit_transform([['hot'],['warm'],['warm'],['cold']]).reshape((1,-1))[0]` will produce the desired output. AFAIK no need to install external modules (might just be old question too).

Answer (score 3):

You use ordinal encoding to preserve order of categorical data i.e. cold, warm, hot; low, medium, high. You use label encoding or one hot for categorical data, where there's no order in data i.e. dog, cat, whale. Check this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-categorical-variable-encoding-305f3361fd02) on medium. It explains these concepts well.

Comment: Perhaps there's an inconsistency in terminology, but this seems incorrect with regards to the OP's question on sklearn's LabelEncoder; it encodes as integers from 0 to n_classes-1, the same as OrdinalEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode multiple columns at once using `OrdinalEncoder`, while `LabelEncoder` can handle only one column.

e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  ["a", "1", "lable1"],
  ["a", "2", "lable0"],
  ["b", "3", "lable1"],
  ["b", "4", "lable1"],
], columns=["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"])

OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(df)
>>> array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 2., 1.],
       [1., 3., 1.]])

OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(df[["col_1", "col_2"]])
>>> array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 2.],
       [1., 3.]])

LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df)
>>> ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (4, 3) instead.

LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df["col_1"])
>>> array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```