# How to perform one hot encoding on multiple categorical columns

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas

I am trying to perform one-hot encoding on some categorical columns. From the tutorial I am following, I am supposed to do LabelEncoding before One hot encoding. I have successfully performed the labelencoding as shown below

```
#categorical data
categorical_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
# instantiate labelencoder object
le = LabelEncoder()
# apply le on categorical feature columns
data[categorical_cols] = data[categorical_cols].apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
```

Now I am stuck with how to perform one hot encoding and then join the encoded columns to the dataframe (data).

Please how do I do this?

Comment: You probably don't want to use label encoding [ideally it should be used for target variable]. Do you need one-hot encoding (same as pd.get_dummies()) or ordinal encoding (pd.factorize()) or something else? https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-categorical-variable-encoding-305f3361fd02 will help you choose your encoding & sample code is also provided.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

LabelEncoder is not made to transform the data but the target (also known as *labels*) as explained [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/39319/93744). If you want to encode the data you should use OrdinalEncoder.

### If you really need to do it this way:

```
categorical_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
# instantiate labelencoder object
le = LabelEncoder()

# apply le on categorical feature columns
data[categorical_cols] = data[categorical_cols].apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))    
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

#One-hot-encode the categorical columns.
#Unfortunately outputs an array instead of dataframe.
array_hot_encoded = ohe.fit_transform(data[categorical_cols])

#Convert it to df
data_hot_encoded = pd.DataFrame(array_hot_encoded, index=data.index)

#Extract only the columns that didnt need to be encoded
data_other_cols = data.drop(columns=categorical_cols)

#Concatenate the two dataframes : 
data_out = pd.concat([data_hot_encoded, data_other_cols], axis=1)
```

### Otherwise:

I suggest you to use [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) if you want to achieve one-hot-encoding from raw data (without having to use OrdinalEncoder before) :

```
#categorical data
categorical_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 

#import pandas as pd
df = pd.get_dummies(data, columns = categorical_cols)
```

You can also use *drop_first* argument to remove one of the *one-hot-encoded* columns, as [some models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/329281/279276) require.

Comment: pandas.get_dummies did the job for me, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**You can do dummy encoding using Pandas in order to get one-hot encoding as shown below:**

```
import pandas as pd

# Multiple categorical columns
categorical_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

pd.get_dummies(data, columns=categorical_cols)
```

**If you want to do one-hot encoding using sklearn library, you can get it done as shown below:**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()

transformed_data = onehotencoder.fit_transform(data[categorical_cols])

# the above transformed_data is an array so convert it to dataframe
encoded_data = pd.DataFrame(transformed_data, index=data.index)

# now concatenate the original data and the encoded data using pandas
concatenated_data = pd.concat([data, encoded_data], axis=1)
```

**If a single column has more than 500 categories, the aforementioned way of one-hot encoding is not a good approach**. **In this case, we can do one-hot encoding for the top 10 or 20 categories that are occurring most for a particular column. A sample code is shown below:**

```
categorical_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# Let's say we have a column 'b' which has more than 500 categories.
# Find the top 10 most frequent categories for column 'b'
data.b.value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(20)

# make a list of the most frequent categories of the column
top_10_occurring_cat = [cat for cat in data.b.value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(10).index]

# now make the 10 binary variables
for cat in top_10_occurring_cat:
    data[cat] = np.where(data['b'] == cat, 1, 0) # whenever data['b'] == cat replace it with 1 else 0

# This is done for one categorical column, similarly you can repeat for all categorical columns
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `make_column_transformer` and `fit_transform` for this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import oneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

transformer=make_column_transformer(oneHotEncoder(),categorical_column,remainder="passthrough")
transformed=transformer.fit_transform(data)
transformed_df=pd.dataframe(transforme,columns=transformer.get_feature_names())
```

You will get the data frame which has both encoded categorical data and other numerical columns

Answer (score 2):

#### Create a Pandas DataFrame with multiple one-hot-encoded columns

Let's say you have a Pandas dataframe `flags` with many columns you want to one-hot-encode.

You want a Pandas dataframe `flags_ohe`, which has the same columns as `flags`, but columns `'Mainhue', 'Landmass','Zone','Language','Religion', 'Topleft', 'Botright'` are replaced with one-hot-encoded versions with clear column names such as `Mainhue_red` and `Mainhue_blue`.

```
flags_ohe = flags
categorical_columns = ['Landmass','Zone','Language','Religion', 
                       'Mainhue', 'Topleft', 'Botright']
for col in categorical_columns:
    col_ohe = pd.get_dummies(flags[col], prefix=col)
    flags_ohe = pd.concat((flags_ohe, col_ohe), axis=1).drop(col, axis=1)
```

### Here's before.

```
print(flags.columns)

# Output:
# Index(['Name', 'Landmass', 'Zone', 'Area', 'Population', 'Language',
#  'Religion', 'Bars', 'Stripes', 'Colors', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Gold',
#  'White', 'Black', 'Orange', 'Mainhue', 'Circles', 'Crosses', 'Saltires',
#  'Quarters', 'Sunstars', 'Crescent', 'Triangle', 'Icon', 'Animate',
#  'Text', 'Topleft', 'Botright'],
# dtype='object')
# dtype='object')
```

### Here's after.

```
print(flags_ohe.columns)

# Output:
# Index(['Name', 'Area', 'Population', 'Bars', 'Stripes', 'Colors', 'Red',
#  'Green', 'Blue', 'Gold', 'White', 'Black', 'Orange', 'Circles',
#  'Crosses', 'Saltires', 'Quarters', 'Sunstars', 'Crescent', 'Triangle',
#  'Icon', 'Animate', 'Text', 'Landmass_1', 'Landmass_2', 'Landmass_3',
#  'Landmass_4', 'Landmass_5', 'Landmass_6', 'Zone_1', 'Zone_2', 'Zone_3',
#  'Zone_4', 'Language_1', 'Language_2', 'Language_3', 'Language_4',
#  'Language_5', 'Language_6', 'Language_7', 'Language_8', 'Language_9',
#  'Language_10', 'Religion_0', 'Religion_1', 'Religion_2', 'Religion_3',
#  'Religion_4', 'Religion_5', 'Religion_6', 'Religion_7', 'Mainhue_black',
#  'Mainhue_blue', 'Mainhue_brown', 'Mainhue_gold', 'Mainhue_green',
#  'Mainhue_orange', 'Mainhue_red', 'Mainhue_white', 'Topleft_black',
#  'Topleft_blue', 'Topleft_gold', 'Topleft_green', 'Topleft_orange',
#  'Topleft_red', 'Topleft_white', 'Botright_black', 'Botright_blue',
#  'Botright_brown', 'Botright_gold', 'Botright_green', 'Botright_orange',
#  'Botright_red', 'Botright_white'],
# dtype='object')
```