# On gradient boosting and types of encodings

Tags: encoding, boosting, categorical-encoding, one-hot-encoding

I am having a look at this [material](https://github.com/lesteve/euroscipy-2019-scikit-learn-tutorial/blob/master/notebooks/02_basic_preprocessing.ipynb) and I have found the following statement:

> For this class of models [Gradient Boosting Machine algorithms] [...] it is both safe and significantly
> more computationally efficient use an arbitrary integer encoding [also known as Numeric Encoding] for
> the categorical variable even if the ordering is arbitrary [instead of
> One-Hot encoding].

Do you know some references that support this statement? I get that Numeric Encoding is more computationally efficient than One-Hot Encoding, but I would like to know more about their supposed equivalence to encode unordered categorical variables in Gradient Boosting Methods.

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77880/55122

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a feature of tree-based models in general, not just gradient boosting trees.

Not exactly a reference, but [this Medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-is-making-your-tree-based-ensembles-worse-heres-why-d64b282b5769) explains why ordinal encoding is often more efficient.

On the topic of safety, I think the author should have said that the use of ordinal encoding is *more* safe compared to linear methods, but still not perfectly safe.  It's possible for decision-tree methods to find spurious rules within ordinal encodings, but they don't have the strong assumptions about numeric semantics that linear methods do.

> . . . I would like to know more about their supposed equivalence to encode unordered categorical variables . . .

Any rule derived with one-hot encoding can also be represented with ordinal encoding, it just might take more splits.

To illustrate, suppose you have a categorical variable `foo` with possible values `spam`, `ham`, `eggs`.  A one-hot encoding would create 3 dummy variables, `is_spam`, `is_ham`, `is_eggs`.  Let's say an arbitrary ordinal encoding assigns `spam` = 1, `ham` = 2, and `eggs` = 3.

Suppose the OHE decision tree splits on `is_eggs = 1`.  This can be represented in the ordinal decision tree by the split `foo > 2`.  Suppose the OHE tree splits on `is_ham = 1`.  The ordinal tree will require two splits: `foo > 1` then `foo < 3`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will digest this new information and I will come back ;-)

Comment: Starting from the link you @zachdj posted, after a couple of steps I have found this article: https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/. It is more focused on one-hot encoding and random forests, however I think that for the moment I am quite satisfied and I draw the following conclusion: one-hot encoding may behaves so poorly in tree-based methods that label/numeric encoding may outperform it. I leave the question open just in case we receive more insights. Thanks again!

Comment: For those who view this question but don't want to read the articles, here's the upshot: One-hot encoding introduces a lot of sparse binary variables;  this hurts runtime performance because the decision tree has more variables to consider when splitting.  It also can hurt accuracy because you're less likely to get a high-purity split early in the tree with OHE vs. ordinal encoding.